# How to select the object using class instead of ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, addeventlistener

I'm trying to toggle two div using **class** selector but it does not work. If I use **ID** then it works. Below are my snippet. As I read class selector select array of html then I use index[0] to it but still did not work. I had also used querySelector() but still did not work. I'll appreciate if anyone can help.
Thanks!

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("filt-daily"),
  d = document.getElementsByClassName("filt-monthly"),
  t = document.getElementsByClassName("switcher"),
  m = document.getElementsByClassName("daily"),
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("monthly");

e[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  t[0].checked = false;
  e[0].classList.add('toggler--is-active');
  d[0].classList.remove('toggler--is-active');
  m[0].classList.remove('hide');
  y[0].classList.add('hide');
});

d[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  t[0].checked = true;
  d[0].classList.add('toggler--is-active');
  e[0].classList.remove('toggler--is-active');
  m[0].classList.add('hide');
  y[0].classList.remove('hide');
});

t[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  d[0].classList.toggle('toggler--is-active');
  e[0].classList.toggle('toggler--is-active');
  m[0].classList.toggle('hide');
  y[0].classList.toggle('hide');
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

.toggle,
.toggler {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggler {
  color: #ccc5c5;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.toggler--is-active {
  color: #12577f;
}

.b {
  display: block;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 6;
}

.check:checked~.switch {
  right: 2px;
  left: 57.5%;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-delay: 0.08s, 0s;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 57.5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 36px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.08s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<center><label class="filt-daily toggler toggler--is-active" id="filt-daily">Daily</label>
  <div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switcher" class="switcher check">
    <b class="b switch"></b>
  </div>
  <label class="filt-monthly toggler" id="filt-monthly">Monthly</label>
</center><br>
<div class="daily" id="daily">
  <h2>daily menu</h2>
</div>
<div class="monthly hide" id="monthly">
  <h2>monthly menu</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have `class="filt-daily"` or `class="filt-monthly"` in the HTML.

Comment: `t.checked` needs to be `t[0].checked`, and the same for all the `.classList.toggle()` calls.

Comment: Now you're getting the error because you have no `class="switcher"`. Why is this so hard to understand? Look at the line where the error happens, it tells you which one is missing.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a class when there's just one element? Classes are useful when you have multiple elements that should be processed similarly. If an element is unique, use its ID.

Comment: Now the code works. What's the question?

Comment: Use `document.querySelector()` so you don't have to index it.

Comment: I want this toggle in a CMS where they don't provide to add the ID

Comment: Then why do you have IDs in your sample HTML?

Comment: Just for checking..

Comment: This has been resolved now Thank you so much @Barmar